# Hollow wall anchoring options for steel sided van cooler

Tags: steel, anchor

Would a hollow wall anchor, such as a "Midwest Fastener 3/8" x 2-1/16" SR Zinc Expansion Hollow Wall Anchor" be suitable for securing strut channel to the exterior of a steel sided van cooler?

I am retrofitting the air conditioner in an old (1970's) van cooler. I will be using a window-type air conditioner with a CoolBot to lower the temperate.

Even though the case to the air conditioner is fastened to the frame of the van, I would like to add some additional support/protection in the form of a cage built with strut channel. The van is framed with 2x4's and the cavities between studs are filled with a blow in insulation.

The studs are wider than the air conditioner by several inches on either side, so the cage would not fit snugly to the air conditioner if I used the studs to anchor the strut channel. I was considering other options, such as a hollow wall anchor or even putting a carriage bolt through the wall to the other side. I can see an electrician previously anchored a piece of strut to the van using just a regular screw, and it seems to be anchored securely.

Any input or advice would be helpful.

Comment: What exact channel? And how thick is the sheet metal? Have you considered drilling new holes in your struts that are sized for sheet metal screws? With the correct drill bit (it's well below 10 USD), you can easily drill through that channel. From my recollection of typical Unistrut, there's plenty of meat there for drilling. You might sand the bearing surface around the drilled holes a little afterward to avoid scratching the sheet metal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement.

Comment: @RMDman, sounds like a framing question for a van home.

Comment: @popham, I didn't get that.  I thought it was about stuffing a window AC in a van.  Didn't consider it was a home.

Comment: Looks like you can get a cheap pop rivet gun on Amazon too. Might be a nice tool to have in this situation.

Comment: @popham The channel is 12 gauge, 1-5/8 Inch. I do not know the thickness of the sheet metal, but I could try and figure that out tomorrow. I had not considered using sheet metal screws, but that seems like a viable option. Maybe sheet metal screws are what the electrician previously used to anchor the piece of piece of channel. However, he used a fender washer and went through one of the existing holes in the strut.

Comment: If i may ask, how big is this van?   I purchased the smallest window AC unit for a room in a rental unit,  (9x16 room)  and that thing  can cool the room enough to hang meat.  What will a window AC unit do in a van?

Answer (score 2):

Your spec'ed drywall anchors are designed with 1/2" material in mind. They won't work for sheet metal. Instead you want sheet metal screws. Short ones I imagine based on your problem description, where the 2-1/16" length anchors you spec'ed confused me.

Based on your 12 gauge strut and second ply that's probably 18 gauge or thinner, #10-3/4" self drilling screws will be plenty long. With the self drilling tip, you don't need a drill bit, but a little pilot hole can be nice. Get hex heads so that the screws don't wobble as you drill with them.

Pop rivets might be the best tool for this job, but they require some special tooling that would probably require more than just a trip to the local hardware store.